# How to get total count of pointers when pointers are on multiple views?

Tags: android, motionevent, android-touch-event

When multiple pointers are on different views, how can I get the total number of pointers on screen? I have multiple views on screen and if a pointer is not on the related area of the view, view will return `false` in `ON_DOWN` case of `onTouchEvent`.

When first finger is on a view and second one touches to another view both views will return "1" for `getPointerCount` method. Is there any way to get total pointer count on entire screen regardless of which view handles the touch of pointer?

**Edit:** `Views` are not in the same parent `ViewGroup`, that is why `onInterceptTouch` won't return the total pointer count. I can put `onInterceptTouch` to very root `ViewGroup`, however I was hoping Android would give total count of pointers without some dirty workaround like this.

Comment: All views reside inside a ViewGroup as root view. ViewGroup class has method: [`onInterceptTouch()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)). As long as you return false from it, events are passed through it, then to child views. So, in theory,  parent ViewGroup of the Views can monitor all pointers. You'll need to test is to be sure though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do it using the methods that are called on `Activity` but as @S.D. pointed out, you can use the `onInterceptTouchEvent` of the `ViewGroup` to do it:

**MyLinearLayout.java**

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.e("TOUCHES", "num: " + ev.getPointerCount());

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

**mylayout.xml**

```
<mypackage.MyLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"/>

</mypackage.MyLinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

        final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        final TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);

        t1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                t1.setText(""+motionEvent.getPointerCount());
                return true;
            }
        });

        t2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                t2.setText(""+motionEvent.getPointerCount());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This example will set the texts of the t1 and t2 `TextView`s with the `getPointerCount()` of the `MotionEvent` received by each `TextView`, and will Log the total value of `getPointerCount()` of the `MotionEvent` received by the `MyLinearLayout`

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom ViewGroup that intercept all touch events passed down.

You need to understand how this work in Android:

- `ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` allow a ViewGroup to intercept touch event before they reach children. If you return `true` here you'll receive subsequent touch events in `onTouchEvent()` and children will not receive any more touch event until the current event is over (pointer removed)
- children view can request the parent to disallow interception with `ViewGroup.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)`: they usually do when they recognize a touch event in progress and they do not want the parent to interrupt it. If the ViewGroup receive this request it MUST pass it to the parent and honor it (= do not intercept events from here on)
- internally a `ViewGroup` will not call `onInterceptTouchEvent` after `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` is received

If you need to listen to every touch event, even if the children disallowed interception you need to trick the `ViewGroup` into thinking it has not been disallowed but you still need to honor the disallow (avoid intercepting touch events).

This is a class I wrote for one of my projects that does exactly that:

```
public class InterceptTouchFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private boolean mDisallowIntercept;

    public interface OnInterceptTouchEventListener {
        /**
         * If disallowIntercept is true the touch event can't be stealed and the return value is ignored.
         * @see android.view.ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
         */
        boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(InterceptTouchFrameLayout view, MotionEvent ev, boolean disallowIntercept);

        /**
         * @see android.view.View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
         */
        public boolean onTouchEvent(InterceptTouchFrameLayout view, MotionEvent event);
    }

    private static final class DummyInterceptTouchEventListener implements OnInterceptTouchEventListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(InterceptTouchFrameLayout view, MotionEvent ev, boolean disallowIntercept) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(InterceptTouchFrameLayout view, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static final OnInterceptTouchEventListener DUMMY_LISTENER = new DummyInterceptTouchEventListener();

    private OnInterceptTouchEventListener mInterceptTouchEventListener = DUMMY_LISTENER;

    public InterceptTouchFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InterceptTouchFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InterceptTouchFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
        mDisallowIntercept = disallowIntercept;
    }

    public void setOnInterceptTouchEventListener(OnInterceptTouchEventListener interceptTouchEventListener) {
        mInterceptTouchEventListener = interceptTouchEventListener != null ? interceptTouchEventListener : DUMMY_LISTENER;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean stealTouchEvent = mInterceptTouchEventListener.onInterceptTouchEvent(this, ev, mDisallowIntercept);
        return stealTouchEvent && !mDisallowIntercept || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean handled = mInterceptTouchEventListener.onTouchEvent(this, event);
        return handled || super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

You just set your listener with: `view.setOnInterceptTouchEventListener()`

Inside that listener you can keep a count of pointers down (inside the `onIntercetTouchEvent()` method).
Just place that layout as root of your layout (full screen).

If you try to do the same without the disallow trick you can end up with incorrect information because you are not granted to receive all touch events.